# Python3 and SQLite3 - Why is this function undefined?

Tags: python-3.x

```
import sqlite3 as sq3

class DataModule:
    
    def del_tbl(tbl_Name):
        sq3.Connection("csm").cursor().execute("DROP TABLE IF EXSISTS '{}'".format(tbl_Name))
        print("Table [{}] has beeen deleted".format(tbl))
    
    def createTable(tableName,cmd):
        del_tbl("tbl_login")
        del_tbl("tbl_address")
        cmd=str.join(", ",cmd)
        sq3.Connection("csm").cursor().execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {} ({}); ".format(tableName, cmd))
```

The output now says:

> ```
> Error: ("name 'del_tbl' is not defined",)
> Error: ("name 'del_tbl' is not defined",)
> Press any key to continue . . .
> ```

I'm sure its something really simple that I've missed

Comment: Is there a reason why `self` isn't the first argument to those methods? Are they meant to be class methods rather than instance methods?

Comment: I was going to return true/false depending if they were successful

Answer (score 1):

This is not a function, but a class method, you have to call it with self. prefix (and also add it to the method definition):

```
import sqlite3 as sq3

class DataModule:
    
    def del_tbl(self, tbl_Name):
        sq3.Connection("csm").cursor().execute("DROP TABLE IF EXSISTS '{}'".format(tbl_Name))
        print("Table [{}] has beeen deleted".format(tbl))
    
    def createTable(self, tableName,cmd):
        self.del_tbl("tbl_login")
        self.del_tbl("tbl_address")
        cmd=str.join(", ",cmd)
        sq3.Connection("csm").cursor().execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {} ({}); "
```

Comment: Thank you. That bit now works, but the createTable now says:  start() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'. Sorry!

Comment: Please provide context, but probably you have forgot to provide tableName or cmd argument to it (it requires 2 arguments)